# Format Knockout Number in subtotal

Tags: html, model-view-controller, knockout.js

I am writing an application with MVC and Knockout. The user can write the price of some elements and are enabled to write comma or dot, but the only value accepted is numeric with dot.

I have already done the structure of all system but when i try to valorize the price with comma, the result in the value and subtotal is NaN. Otherwise, all works fine with dot.

This is the input of price and the subtotal:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: Price" validate-type="price" step="0.01" min="0">
<p class="form-control-static" data-bind="text: formattedPrice"></p>
```

This is the function to elaborate date and show the subtotal:

```
function SfuffItem(obj) {
var self = this;
$.extend(self, obj);
self.Qta = ko.observable(obj.Qta);
self.Price = ko.observable(obj.Price);

self.Subtotal = ko.computed(function () {
    return self.Qta() * self.Price();
}, self);
self.formattedPrice = ko.computed(function () {
    var price = self.Subtotal();
    return price ? price.toFixed(2) + ' €' : "0";
});
}

pagemodel.prepareData = function (data) {
    data.Stuff = self.stuff();
};
```

I have tried to replace data but no solution online works in my code

Comment: If it is a dot then it can be recognised as a number but with a comma it would need to be a string. Could you not write some logic to check for commas and convert as necessary?

Comment: Yes is possible. How can i do this in Knockout?